# Brackets on GitHub issues

Tags: issue-tracking, github

Does anyone know how to include brackets in a comment on GitHub issues?

I'm trying to add something like this, but nothing shows up:

```
<dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="dotless.Core" publicKeyToken="96b446c9e63eae34" culture="neutral" />
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.2.0" newVersion="1.2.2.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I've already tried to surround everything with `<pre></pre>`, "`", and others, but nothing seems to work. It just won't show up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try to HTML encode these?

```
< to - &lt;
> to - &gt;
& to - &amp;
```

Comment: Nice, that worked. However, I'm thinking that there should be an easier way.

Comment: Still haven't found a better way of doing this, so this should be the right answer. Thanks.